# Post values in ASP .Net hiddenfield when using masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

In my ASP .Net Form application I need to post some data using hiddenfields.

1. Need to set the values dynamically in page load in the code behind file
2. Have to use the hidden fileds in a web form which using a masterpage.

I have to add `runat="server"` attribute as need to access the field in code behind file to assign value dynamically..... There the problem begins.

eg:

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="uname" value="abc" />
```

**converts to following by ASP .Net in run time**

```
 <input name="ctl00$content$uname" type="hidden" id="content_uname" value="abc" />
```

So a diffrent filed `name="ctl00$content$uname"` gets posted.

I tried adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` but still a different named field creates by ASP .Net in run time for `name` field as following

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="uname" runat="server" Value="abc" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

**Converts to following by asp .net**

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$content$uname" id="uname" value="abc" />
```

If somebody can guide me of how to post values using hiddenfields by assingning values in run time in code beghind in a masterpage environment in ASP .Net, would be really grateful. Thanks...

Comment: Well, the answer is simple... use your first example but set the `name` attribute yourself so that it won't be generated by .NET based on the dynamic ID... at least AFAIK. You could also use following notation in most cases if I'm not mistaken : `<input type="hidden" id="uname" name="uname" value="<%= yourServerSideVariable %>" />`

Comment: Ended up as this ----->>  <input name="ctl00$content$uname" type="hidden" id="content_uname" value="abc" />

Comment: @JibW: Did you remember to take out `runat="server"`?  It shouldn't be modifying any markup that's not running at the server.  Also, why do you need to control the name anyway?  Is it posting to a different website?  If you're posting back to the same application then usually WebForms handles that for you and you just access the values of the server-side controls.

Comment: I don't understand what is preventing you from referencing the hidden values once they are rendered on the page?

Comment: @David: Yes I have to post values to external web site. Therefore name fields has to be the posting field. When it appends "content_" text in to name filed it posts a different field and not the required.

Comment: @entropic: I need to assign value to the hidden field in the page load event dynamically. Reading hidden field values is ok. but checking for a way to assign the value for reqired hidden filed in page load in runtime so that I can pass the specific value for the field to the external server where I need it to get posted....(uname=abc NOT ctl00$content$uname=abc)

Comment: I see, then you need to get rid of the "runat=server" tag and assign it using direct statements - just as Bartdude says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you use `runat="server"` you essentially give WebForms control over that, well, "control".  Which means that WebForms is going to dictate the resulting markup.  Since you need granular control over the markup, you need to create it manually:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uname" />
```

Since this is just plain HTML, the WebForms rendering engine won't modify it.  Then to assign a value to this from server-side code, you'd use an inline server-side statement:

```
<input type="hidden" name="uname" value="<%= SomePageMember %>" />
```

In this case, `SomePageMember` is a `public` or `protected` class member for the page's class.  Something like this:

```
protected string SomePageMember { get; set; }
```

This will allow the UI page (which inherits from the code-behind class) to inject that value directly in the markup, while still giving you granular control over the markup itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the value set via a server tag and not user `runat="server"`

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" id="uname" name="uname" value="<%= HiddenValue %>" />
```

Create a global variable named `HiddenValue` and set the value when the page loads.

Edit: Just realized that this the same advice as @Bartdude.